# Make box-shadow wider than element itself

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a box-shadow CSS call wider than the HTML element to which we are applying it, while keeping the same height as the element to which we are applying it? I can increase the spread, but that will increase the height. As you can see in my snippet, the max width the box-shadow is only as wide as the `.box` div. Is there a reason why we would not want the box shadow ever wider than the HTML element or why there would be a restriction to this?

```css
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  box-shadow: 55px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.container-spread {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.box-spread {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  box-shadow: 55px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">box</div>
  container
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div class="container-spread">
  <div class="box-spread">box</div>
  container
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's not possible to use the `spread-radius` value to extend the shadow in just the horizontal or vertical directions you can add multiple drop shadows to a single element, the only downside being that any over lap will produce regions of darker shadow. But with a little bit of math  you can line them up easily enough.

[box-shadow at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

```css
.container{ background-color:gray; height:100px; width:100px; }
.box{ background-color:blue; 
    height:50px; 
    width:50px; 
    box-shadow:55px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               105px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               155px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2) ; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">box</div>
  container
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of the pseudo element to enlarge the element and then apply `box-shadow`. `height: 100%` will make sure the height of the box-shadow is same as the element. The `width` value will be the key value to change.

```css
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.box::after {
  box-shadow: 85px 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: " ";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">box</div>
  container
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

While `box-shadow` does have a *spread* setting, it applies to all sides. As far as I know there is no way of adjusting just the horizontal or vertical size of a box shadow.

You could potentially use two (or more) box shadows to achieve the effect, but it is really only applicable when the spread is set to `0`

```css
.container{ background-color:gray; height:100px; width:100px; }
.box{ background-color:blue; height:50px; width:50px;
  box-shadow: 
     55px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
     5px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">box</div>
  container
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need this

```css
.container{ background-color:gray; height:100px; width:100px; }
.box{ background-color:blue; height:50px; width:50px; box-shadow:0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">box</div>
  container
</div>
```

Comment: Downvote because.... ? Please, to all the trolls that runs in this place, when you downvote, leave a comment with the explanation. Don't be childs or just-borned people...

Comment: I apologize Marcos, I thought the reason for the downvote was obvious. I downvoted because this does not answer my question and the others do. I am looking for a box-shadow that does not increase the height of the shadow.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I understand wrong the question, so when I write the answer I think that you need the box shadow in the own box. If you have solved the issue, congratulations! See you later :)

Comment: If you'd like, I can remove the -1 if you edit the answer with another solution.